# Using backtick command execution in Git alias

Tags: git, msysgit, git-bash, backticks, git-alias

Here's a simple example to demonstrate my problem. If I do:

```
git commit -m "`date --utc`"
```

It executes `date --utc`, and puts the result inside the commit message.

However, when I alias it to testcomit:

```
git config --global alias.testcommit 'commit -m "`date --utc`"'
```

Doing `git testcommit` does not execute the `` `date --utc` `` part, it instead puts it verbatim in the commit message.

So, how do I get this alias to execute `date --utc`?

Comment: I *think* you can use `git config --global alias.testcommit '!git commit -m "$(date --utc)"'`. The trick is the `!`, which makes the whole alias a shell command (hence the `git` in there), read more [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). (`$()` instead of backticks is unrelated, but you should start using it.) But you do know the time of a commit is stored by default, so there's no reason to put it in the message?

Comment: @Biffen thanks let me try that to see if it works. I do know about the time, this is just an example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Biffen, amazing! it worked. Please put it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command.

So you can use:

```
git config --global alias.testcommit '!git commit -m "$(date --utc)"'
```

Note that you have to put `git` in there, since you're now specifying the *whole* shell command.

(`$()` instead of backticks is unrelated, but it's better so you should start using it.)